# How to implement a select list correctly?

Tags: angular, typescript

How can I implement a selection list using these three models? I do so:

html:

```html
<ng-container [(ngModel)]='user.id' name="id" >
  <select *ngFor="let userRole of userRoles" required>
    <option *ngFor="let role of roles" [ngValue]="role.role_id">
      {{role.name}}
    </option>
  </select>
</ng-container>
```

But in the end  get a duplicate of the "select" component. And I get this error:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No value accessor for form
>   control with name: 'id' Error: No value accessor for form control with
>   name: 'id'

Comment: In your `User` class shouldn't it be `id` instead of `d`?

Comment: `ng-container`s are angular elements that are meant to disappear. You can't bind anything to it.

Comment: @AugustinR I forgot to add here.

Comment: @trichetriche I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @user10190772 inspect your select in your borwser : you won't see any `ng-container` : they're used as placeholders to content, not as actual elements. By using attributes on it, you're only losing them (or in some cases, making the application crash)

Comment: @trichetriche Oh, ok, the bug, I sorted it out, but I have a duplicate component, due to the fact that I have two cycles, how can I write get rid of?

Comment: What do you mean by "two cycles"

Comment: @trichetriche `*ngFor="let userRole of userRoles"` and `*ngFor="let role of roles"  `

Comment: Okay, you want a single select that displays the roles, and that uses their ID as a value ? and the user should have the possibility of selecting several ones ?

Comment: @trichetriche Yes, but  just a not few, but one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with your model.

```
export class User {
  constructor(
    public id: number,
    public role: Role,
  ) {}
}

export class Role {
  constructor(
    public id: number,
    public label: string,
  ) {}
}
```

Now with your select.

```
<select [(ngModel)]="user.roles">
  <option *ngFor="let role of roles" [ngValue]="role"> {{ role.label }} </option>
</select>
```

Which gives as a result, [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4c3vxe?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)